# Installed library packages cannot be found on OpenWRT

Tags: package-management, libraries, openwrt, cross-compilation

I have been compiling / installing custom packages for OpenWRT. I kept running into problems when I was compiling getting errors like:

```
Package x is missing dependencies for the following libraries:
libc.so.6
```

I solved this by adding the line `libc.so.6` to a `libc.provides` file.

Now I am running into this error:

[image: OpenWRT Screenshot]

Even though the packages are installed (in the list of installed packages and in the `bin` folder), they don't get run when I type them in.

Somebody suggested that it may be because a linked library is missing.

If anybody has any idea, I would appreciate any comments!

**Update**

In another install where `amld` **is working**, and `amldmonitor` **is not**

```
root@OpenWrt:~# file /bin/amld
/bin/amld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), corrupted section header size
root@OpenWrt:~# file /bin/amldmonitor
/bin/amldmonitor: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), corrupted section header size
```

Question on [r/openwrt](http://www.reddit.com/r/openwrt/comments/1rfhtt/missing_dependencies_after_recompile/)

Comment: What says `ls -l /bin/amld` ?

Comment: Hey, the output is,`-rwxr-xr-x 1    root    root        57800 Dec    3 14:38 /bin/amld`

Comment: Since this is tagged cross-compilation, I'm guessing you're trying to run an executable built on a 32-bit system using a 64-bit system. Is that the case?

Comment: Nope, I am compiling on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit for an OpenWRT x86 target system

Comment: Furthermore, I have successfully compiled / run all 3 of the above packages following the same steps.

I assume that, when recompiling, something in the build environment is breaking itself... that is my assumption but I really can't be sure / don't have a clue

Comment: From your `ls` output colours, I bet the ones in blue are symlinks to binaries in another directory, and `/bin` is not included in `$PATH`. What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: The output is, `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin`. In another VM where 2 of the packages work and 1 can't be found, they are all the same colour in the `ls` output

Comment: The problem is not with `$PATH`, although blue generally means symlinks and green executables (`ls` must be linked to `busybox`). Have you tried running `/bin/amld`? I don't know if it will work, though.

Comment: Yeah I have tried putting the full path in, same symptoms.

Comment: What does ldd /bin/amld return?

Comment: What is the exact error when you try with the full path ? What's the output of `file /bin/amld` ?

Comment: @hildred & @Vinz, the output is `/bin/ash: /bin/amld: not found` and th

Comment: Sorry @Vinz, see updated question

Comment: what does `ldd /bin/amld` gives you as a result ?

Comment: `root@OpenWrt:/# ldd /bin/amld`

`-ash: /bin/amld: not found`

Comment: Are you sure your OpenWRT is a 32-bit system ?

Comment: The target I set in `menuconfig` is x86 and I have had all of these packages working in some install at one stage or another (following the same steps)

Comment: Then it seems your `libc.provides` didn't really solve the problem... `libc` is very essential on Linux, and that must be the culprit of the problem.

Comment: I think you are definitely right... When I try to compile without it, I get `Package amld is missing dependencies for the following libraries: libc.so.6`. I can't find any other `.provides` files which provide a `libc.so.6`, only `libc.so.0`... Any ideas where to go from here? I'll give a 100 bounty in a couple of days to anybody who comes up with a solution :P

Comment: I see OpenWRT uses uClibc. Try running `opkg list libc*` to see a list of available packages related to libc6. If there's something named like `libc6-dev`, install it like `opkg install libc6-dev`. I'm talking based on the documentation for `opkg`, which is here: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg

Comment: @JosephR. The file names in cyan (not blue) are symbolic links to `busybox`.

Comment: `opkg update` maybe?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior, The only package I can see that could possibly related is, `libc` and that is already installed and up to date. @Naftuli No luck with that either.

Comment: Could this be related? 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/40416/why-is-lib-libc-so-6-missing

Comment: Looks similar, but the problem could also be that OpenWRT uses `uClibc`, a minimal implementation of `libc`, instead of `glibc`, which is found in Ubuntu, for example. Well, I don't really know that much about `libc`, like if the different implementations are compatible, etc. It seems the compilation went through without linking the libraries, which leaves me confused as well... Based on the link above, try running `ln -s libc.so.0 /lib/libc.so.6` (assuming `libc.so.0` is located under `/lib`).

Comment: I was thinking that too, there is an option in `make menuconfig` to use `eglibc` instead, was going to try that but `svn` is blocked where I am at the moment so it's not possible to download (arghrgrhrgg). I'm doing a full clean of my dev environment and will try linking the files with that command shortly, thanks again

Comment: I ran `find | grep libc.so.0` and it is nowhere to be found, `find | grep libc.so.6`, however,returned this:

`michael@michael-VirtualBox:/$ sudo find | grep libc.so.6
./lib64/libc.so.6
./lib/libc.so.6
./lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
`

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /lib/libc.so.6`?

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 26 10:35 /lib/libc.so.6 -> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Comment: OK, I can't see anything wrong with it. Do not run `ln -s libc.so.0 /lib/libc.so.6`.